# JSONException: Value in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, fatal-error

I want to fetch json data in my app . l used recycle view for displaying data . when l run app l got `FATAL EXCEPTION`

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports, PID: 29757
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"_id":"5c0ba2a7ab233e8499463a95","id":"A0466\/18","entity":"MR","status":"LC","Qcode":"MRLC","Area":"AGA","SubArea":"Movement and landing area","Condition":"Limitations","Subject":"Runway","Modifier":"Closed","message":"RWY 15L\/33R CLSD DUE TO MAINT DURING VMC ONLY.\nCREATED: 05 Dec 2018 06:59:00 \nSOURCE: ORBIYNYX","startdate":"2018-12-07T11:00:00.000Z","enddate":"2018-12-17T13:00:00.000Z","all":"A0466\/18 NOTAMN\nQ) ORBB\/QMRLC\/IV\/NBO\/A\/000\/999\/3316N04414E005\nA) ORBI\nB) 1812071100\nC) 1812171300\nD) MON FRI 1100-1300\nE) RWY 15L\/33R CLSD DUE TO MAINT DURING VMC ONLY.\nCREATED: 05 Dec 2018 06:59:00 \nSOURCE: ORBIYNYX","location":"ORBI","isICAO":true,"Created":"2018-12-05T06:59:00.000Z","key":"A0466\/18-ORBI","type":"airport","StateCode":"IRQ","StateName":"Iraq"},{"_id":"5c0ba2a7ab233e8499463a96","id":"A0409\/18","entity":"MX","status":"LC","Qcode":"MXLC","Area":"AGA","SubArea":"Movement and landing area","Condition":"Limitations","Subject":"Taxiway(s)","Modifier":"Closed","message":"TWY M-NORTH CLSD FOR MAINT BETWEEN SPOT 3 AND TWY M6. UAVS CAN\nOPERATE AT THEIR OWN DISCRETION.\n)\nUNITED STATES NOF DISCLAIMS FOREIGN NOTAM ACCURACY OR COMPLETENESS\nCREATED: 01 Dec 2018 11:44:00 \nSOURCE: LIIAYNYX","startdate":"2018-11-23T04:00:00.000Z","enddate":"2018-12-21T16:00:00.000Z","all":"A0409\/18 NOTAMN\nQ) ORBB\/QMXLC\/IV\/M\/A\/000\/999\/3316N04414E005\nA) ORBI B) 1811230400 C) 1812211600\nD) FRI 0400-1600\nE) TWY M-NORTH CLSD FOR MAINT BETWEEN SPOT 3 AND TWY M6. UAVS CAN\nOPERATE AT THEIR OWN DISCRETION.\n)\nUNITED STATES NOF DISCLAIMS FOREIGN NOTAM ACCURACY OR COMPLETENESS\nCREATED: 01 Dec 2018 11:44:00 \nSOURCE: LIIAYNYX","location":"ORBI","isICAO":true,"Created":"2018-12-01T11:44:00.000Z","key":"A0409\/18-ORBI","type":"airport","StateCode":"IRQ","StateName":"Iraq"},{"_id":"5c0ba2a7ab233e8499463a97","id":"A0386\/18","entity":"FA","status":"TT","Qcode":"FATT","Area":"AGA","SubArea":"Facilities and services","Condition":"Other","Subject":"Aerodrome","Modifier":"AIRAC AIP Amendments","message":"TRIGGER NOTAM - PERM AIRAC AIP AMDT 07\/18 WEF 06 DEC 2018.\nOMNIDIRECTIONAL DEPARTURE CHART UPDATED.\n)\nUNITED STATES NOF DISCLAIMS FOREIGN NOTAM ACCURACY OR COMPLETENESS\nCREATED: 01 Dec 2018 11:44:00 \nSOURCE: LIIAYNYX","startdate":"2018-12-06T00:00:00.000Z","enddate":"2018-12-19T23:59:00.000Z","all":"A0386\/18 NOTAMN\nQ) ORBB\/QFATT\/IV\/BO\/A\/000\/999\/3316N04414E005\nA) ORBI B) 1812060000 C) 1812192359\nE) TRIGGER NOTAM - PERM AIRAC AIP AMDT 07\/18 WEF 06 DEC 2018.\nOMNIDIRECTIONAL DEPARTURE CHART UPDATED.\n)\nUNITED STATES NOF DISCLAIMS FOREIGN NOTAM ACCURACY OR COMPLETENESS\nCREATED: 01 Dec 2018 11:44:00 \nSOURCE: LIIAYNYX","location":"ORBI","isICAO":true,"Created":"2018-12-01T11:44:00.000Z","key":"A0386\/18-ORBI","type":"airport","StateCode":"IRQ","StateName":"Iraq"},{"_id":"5c0ba2a7ab233e8499463a98","id":"A0445\/18","entity":"MT","status":"CM","Qcode":"MTCM","Area":"AGA","SubArea":"Movement and landing area","Condition":"Changes","Subject":"Threshold","Modifier":"Displaced","message":"THR RWY 33L DISPLACED BY 400M. RWY 15R\/33L DECLARED DISTANCES\nCHANGED AS FOLLOWS: TORA, TODA, ASDA, LDA = 2901M. THE FIRST 400M \nOF\nRWY 33L IS NOT AVAILABLE FOR TAXYING ACFT. ALL ACFT DEPARTING FROM\nRWY 33L CAN EXPECT TO ENTER VIA TWY P2 TO P6 OR M6 AND BACKTRACK \nFOR\nDEPARTURE. ALL ACFT ARRIVING ON RWY 15R CAN EXPECT TO BACKTRACK \nAFTER\nLANDING AND VACATE VIA TWY P2 TO P6 OR M6. RWY 15R\/33L INSTRUMENT\nAPPROACHES SUSPENDED. ONLY VISUAL APPROACHES AVAILABLE. CIVILIAN\nAIRCRAFT MAY ONLY USE RWY 15R\/33L DURING DAYLIGHT HOURS AND VMC.\nCREATED: 29 Nov 2018 10:54:00 \nSOURCE: ORBIYNYX","startdate":"2018-11-29T11:00:00.000Z","enddate":"2019-02-28T10:59:00.000Z","all":"A0445\/18 NOTAMN\nQ) ORBB\/QMTCM\/IV\/NBO\/A\/000\/999\/3316N04414E005\nA) ORBI\nB) 1811291100\nC) 1902281059\nE) THR RWY 33L DISPLACED BY 400M. RWY 15R\/33L DECLARED DISTANCES\nCHANGED AS FOLLOWS: TORA, TODA, ASDA, LDA = 2901M. THE FIRST 400M \nO
    F\nRWY 33L IS NOT AVAILABLE FOR TAXYING ACFT. ALL ACFT DEPARTING FROM\nRWY 33L CAN EXPECT TO ENTER VIA TWY P2 TO P6 OR M6 AND BACKTRACK \nFOR\nDEPARTURE. ALL ACFT ARRIVING ON RWY 15R CAN EXPECT TO BACKTRACK \nAFTER\nLANDING AND VACATE VIA TWY P2 TO P6 OR M6. RWY 15R\/33L INSTRUMENT\nAPPROACHES SUSPENDED. ONLY VISUAL APPROACHES AVAILABLE. CIVILIAN\nAIRCRAFT MAY ONLY USE RWY 15R\/33L DURING DAYLIGHT HOURS AND VMC.\nCREATED: 29 Nov 2018 10:54:00 \nSOURCE: ORBIYNYX","location":"ORBI","isICAO":true,"Created":"2018-11-29T10:54:00.000Z","key":"A0445\/18-ORBI","type":"airport","StateCode":"IRQ","StateName":"Iraq"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
        at com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.NotamOrbi$Arr.handleJson(NotamOrbi.kt:90)
        at com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.NotamOrbi$Arr.onPostExecute(NotamOrbi.kt:77)
        at com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.NotamOrbi$Arr.onPostExecute(NotamOrbi.kt:45)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
```

main activity hold all data with recycle view

```
class NotamOrbi : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.notam_orbi)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerDate)
        val data = ArrayList<NOTAMORBI>()
        val adapter = NotamOrbiAdapter(data)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        val url =
            "/locations=orbi"
        Arr().execute(url)


    }


    inner class Arr : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {


        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()


        }

        //        for build connection
        override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String {

            var text: String
            val connection = URL(url[0]).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            connection.connectTimeout = 700

            try {
                connection.connect()
                text = connection.inputStream.use { it.reader().use { reader -> reader.readText() } }


            } finally {

                connection.disconnect()

            }
            return text
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {

            super.onPostExecute(result)
            handleJson(result)


        }

        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg text: String?) {


        }

        @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
        private fun handleJson(jsonString: String?) {

            val jsonObj = JSONObject(jsonString)
//        val result = jsonObj.getJSONObject("result")
//        val response = result.getJSONObject("response")
//        val jsonArray = JSONArray(response.get("data").toString())


            val list = ArrayList<NOTAMORBI>()
            var x = 0
            while (x < jsonObj.length()) {

                val jsonObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject(x.toString())


                list.add(NOTAMORBI(

                        jsonObject.getString("id")

                    )
                )


                x++
            }
            list.forEach(::println)


        }


    }


    class NotamOrbiAdapter(val list: ArrayList<NOTAMORBI>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotamOrbiAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {

            val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.notam_reclycer_card, p0, false)
            return ViewHolder(v)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {

            val data: NOTAMORBI = list[p1]

            p0.id_notam.text = data.idNotam

        }


        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

            val id_notam = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_notam)

        }

    }
}
```

data class

```
data class NOTAMORBI (val idNotam : String)
```

data json

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c0b4ed2ab233e849941925c",
    "id": "A0466/18",
    "entity": "MR",
    "status": "LC",
    "Qcode": "MRLC",
    "Area": "AGA",
    "SubArea": "Movement and landing area",
    "Condition": "Limitations",
    "Subject": "Runway",
    "Modifier": "Closed",
    "message": "RWY 15L/33R CLSD DUE TO MAINT DURING VMC ONLY.\nCREATED: 05 Dec 2018 06:59:00 \nSOURCE: ORBIYNYX",
    "startdate": "2018-12-07T11:00:00.000Z",
    "enddate": "2018-12-17T13:00:00.000Z",
    "all": "A0466/18 NOTAMN\nQ) ORBB/QMRLC/IV/NBO/A/000/999/3316N04414E005\nA) ORBI\nB) 1812071100\nC) 1812171300\nD) MON FRI 1100-1300\nE) RWY 15L/33R CLSD DUE TO MAINT DURING VMC ONLY.\nCREATED: 05 Dec 2018 06:59:00 \nSOURCE: ORBIYNYX",
    "location": "ORBI",
    "isICAO": true,
    "Created": "2018-12-05T06:59:00.000Z",
    "key": "A0466/18-ORBI",
    "type": "airport",
    "StateCode": "IRQ",
    "StateName": "Iraq"
  }
]
```

does any one have solution please ?

Comment: Hey Pablo, can you pls post your `NOTAMORBI` model

Comment: Have you read the error message of the exception? What does it say? The solution is right there, in the error message. But you need to read it.

Comment: @BlueJones l posted

Comment: @JBNizet l read it  but l dont know how to fix . l try but not result

Comment: Please, answer my question: what does it say?

Comment: l told you sir l dont know how to fix  it

Comment: But that's now what I'm asking you to tell. I'm asking you to say what the exception message says. Reading and understanding the error message is the first mandatory step to fix the issue. So, what does the error message say?

Comment: `Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value` and `at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch` this what l am understanding @JBNizet

Comment: No, that's not what it says. The message of the exception is: "Value [ bla bla bla ] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject". And it says that the exception is thrown at line 90 of NotamOrbi.kt. So, at that line, you're constructing a new **JSONObject**, but the value you're passing is a **JSON array**. And indeed, the JSON starts with `[`, which indicates an array. JSON objects start with `{`. So the fix is simple: you need to construct a JSONArray, not a JSONObject.

Comment: thank you . l update my code from `JSONObject to JSONArray`  and he is work fine . but no data display in activity l think the problem the RecyclerView can you check it please RecyclerView  ? l am  junior

Answer (score 1):

Your json is an array, it must be an object; remove the `[` and `]` wrapping your json

Or use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`

Comment: do you think my RecyclerView view okay ?

Comment: Your recyclerview needs a layout manager(unless you've set it in XML). The current issue however is because trying to map an array(your json) to `JSONObject`.

Comment: l update my code from `JSONObject to JSONArray`  and he is work fine . but no data display in activity l think the problem the RecyclerView can you check it please RecyclerView  ? l am  junior

Comment: Add a layout manager to recylcerview `recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)`

Comment: l added but its same         `recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false)`

Comment: The list you set for the adapter never gets populated with data? its just an empty arraylist

Comment: never get data . l have empty activity and no recyclerView and or card view

Comment: l posted all code inside main activity you can check

Comment: Should you not be adding data from the `handleJson()` method?

Then when data is added from that pass the list into the adapter and notify data set changed in adapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184923/discussion-between-blue-jones-and-pabloescobar).

Comment: saw your update code , l have still red line code under adapter `Unresolved reference: adapter` . which adapter do you think he need ?